# Creating dynamic, shaded backgrounds for animations

Tags: python, animation, scripting

I am still new to blender and am working on an animation of a light-responsive protein network in blender-python. I have been asked to create a shaded background whose color changes in accordance with the frequency of light shining on it. My question: how do I code a shaded background in python whose color I can change over the course of the animation:

[image]

Implementing the basic background using Blender's UI was straight forward: add blend-sky to the world and adjust its color's accordingly (Picture 1). Using the info tab, I attempted to recreate these commands in python:

```
 bpy.context.space_data.context = 'WORLD'
 bpy.context.scene.world.use_sky_blend = True
 self.world.horizon_color = (0, 0, 0)
 self.world.zenith_color = (1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

This however only results in "AttributeError: 'SpaceTextEditor' object as no attribute 'context'".

Next, I used a snippet of code from a previous answer I found on this very site (source: [Creating cycles background light (world lighting) from Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23884/creating-cycles-background-light-world-lighting-from-python)), which produced a colored background but lacked the shading of the desired result (Picture 1).

```
 enter codbpy.data.scenes['Scene'].render.engine = 'CYCLES'
 world = bpy.data.worlds['World']
 world.use_nodes = True
 bg = world.node_tree.nodes['Background']
 bg.inputs[0].default_value[:3] = (0.5, .1, 0.6)
 bg.inputs[1].default_value = 1.0e here
```

[image]

Even if one of these two methods had worked, I would still be unsure how to program a change in background color. Can I create background animations using keyframes similar to object animation?  How do I even create the desired type of background in the first place?

Your help is much appreciated.

Pictures: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6qkp.jpg

Comment: Which render engine do you want to use (BI or Cycles)? The solution will be slightly different depending on that.

Comment: See, this is where I out myself as a blender noob: considering all my animations are done with keyframes, is one preferable to the other?

Comment: Cycles is preferrable if you need photorealistic lighting and shading. Your sample scripts seemed to be targeting the older BI render engine.  The world shader is different in Cycles as well.

Comment: Since I do not need photo realistic lighting or shading (indeed the animation is going to be very stylized) would you recommend going with BI? If so, can you recommend a way to achieve my goals?

Comment: Do you need to keyframe the background colour change in python, or would it be enough to keyframe it through the UI?

Comment: I need to keyframe everything in python itself. I have been tasked to not involve the UI at all.

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful to manually keyframe the effect you want in the UI, and then post the blend file here. That would help us recreate the effect in python more accurately.

Comment: To be honest I wouldn't even know how. I can attempt to explain it verbally: given certain wavelengths of light, the program must, at given time-points, change the color of the background accordingly, e.g. the zenith color (from Picture 1) changes from green to red. This transition should be instantly and requires no gradual changes or anything of the sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my solution. It provides for altering the **Horizon Color** and the **Zenith Color**, and assumes you are using the **Blender Internal** render engine.

It also allows you to provide a **list of frame numbers** and **colour values** for setting up **multiple keyframes**.

Also, the default interpolation type for animation curves is **Bezier** which would give you smooth transitions between colors. Because you want abrupt color changes I added code to alter the interpolation mode to **Constant** for the new animation curves.

```
import bpy

scn = bpy.context.scene
world = bpy.context.scene.world
world.use_sky_blend = True

#bgColorList[frameNumber, horizonColor, zenithColor)
bgColorList = [
[1,     (1.0, 1.0, 1.0),    (0.8, 0.8, 0.8)   ],
[15,    (0.8, 0.8, 0.8),    (0.8, 0.8, 0.8)   ],
[30,    (0.5, 0.5, 0.5),    (0.2, 0.2, 0.2)   ],
[45,    (0.8, 0.8, 0.8),    (0.8, 0.8, 0.8)   ],
[60,    (1.0, 1.0, 1.0),    (0.8, 0.8, 0.8)   ],
[75,    (0.5, 0.5, 0.5),    (0.2, 0.2, 0.2)   ]
]

#set up all keyframes for background colors             
for bg in bgColorList:
    frame = bg[0]
    hColor = bg[1]
    zColor = bg[2]

    scn.frame_current = frame
    world.horizon_color = hColor
    world.zenith_color = zColor
    world.keyframe_insert("zenith_color")
    world.keyframe_insert("horizon_color")


#modify the interploation mode of the animationt curve to be consant for immediate changes on frame entry
for f in world.animation_data.action.fcurves:
    if f.data_path == "zenith_color" or f.data_path == "horizon_color":
        for kf in f.keyframe_points:
            kf.interpolation = 'CONSTANT'
```

Comment: Hey, no problem!